# Matplotlib is not working in Jupyter Notebook on Mac

Tags: macos, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Matplotlib is not working in Jupyter Notebook on Mac.    As can be seen below, I think it is installed in the environment.  I have tried upgrading both Jupyter and matplotlib and am able to use matplotlib in other python environments.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I have tried to upgrade Jupyter and Matplotlib `pip install --upgrade matplotlib jupyter`

`pip freeze` shows that 3.8.0 is installed

```
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
anyio==4.0.0
appnope==0.1.3
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.2.3
asttokens==2.4.0
async-lru==2.0.4
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
Babel==2.12.1
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
bleach==6.0.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_5d968ni_yn/croot/certifi_1671487774636/work/certifi
cffi @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_ab19r4bji3/croot/cffi_1670423206034/work
charset-normalizer @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/charset-normalizer_1630003229654/work
click==8.1.3
cloudevents==1.9.0
comm==0.1.4
conda==23.1.0
conda-content-trust @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_11146a2b-93c2-444c-a378-ad4fac363e991s0r1hnp/croots/recipe/conda-content-trust_1658126383571/work
conda-package-handling @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_5f3f459f9v/croot/conda-package-handling_1672865025324/work
conda_package_streaming @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_58gpsa_6af/croot/conda-package-streaming_1670508144037/work
contourpy==1.1.1
cryptography @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_8c_qoky_1b/croot/cryptography_1673298759921/work
cycler==0.12.0
debugpy==1.8.0
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
deprecation==2.1.0
exceptiongroup==1.1.3
executing==2.0.0
fastjsonschema==2.18.0
Flask==2.2.3
fonttools==4.43.0
fqdn==1.5.1
frozenlist==1.3.3
functions-framework==3.3.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_771olrhiqw/croot/idna_1666125579282/work
ipykernel==6.25.2
ipython==8.16.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==8.1.1
isoduration==20.11.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jedi==0.19.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
json5==0.9.14
jsonpointer==2.4
jsonschema==4.19.1
jsonschema-specifications==2023.7.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.7.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.0
jupyter_client==8.3.1
jupyter_core==5.3.2
jupyter_server==2.7.3
jupyter_server_terminals==0.4.4
jupyterlab==4.0.6
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.9
jupyterlab_server==2.25.0
kiwisolver==1.4.5
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.8.0
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mistune==3.0.2
multidict==6.0.4
nbclient==0.8.0
nbconvert==7.8.0
nbformat==5.9.2
nest-asyncio==1.5.8
notebook==7.0.4
notebook_shim==0.2.3
numpy==1.26.0
openai==0.27.5
overrides==7.4.0
packaging==23.0
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==10.0.1
platformdirs==3.10.0
pluggy @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_croot-w6jyveby/pluggy_1648109277227/work
prometheus-client==0.17.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
psutil==5.9.5
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycosat @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_e9xhel3kyj/croot/pycosat_1666805516297/work
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1636541352034/work
Pygments==2.16.1
pyOpenSSL @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/pyopenssl_1643788558760/work
pyparsing==3.1.1
PySocks @ file:///Users/ktietz/ci_310/pysocks_1643961536721/work
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-json-logger==2.0.7
PyYAML==6.0.1
pyzmq==25.1.1
qtconsole==5.4.4
QtPy==2.4.0
referencing==0.30.2
requests==2.31.0
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
rpds-py==0.10.3
ruamel.yaml @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_aeh5mqcw49/croot/ruamel.yaml_1666304555976/work
ruamel.yaml.clib @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_f64xdg2rww/croot/ruamel.yaml.clib_1666302244208/work
Send2Trash==1.8.2
six @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/six_1644875935023/work
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.5
stack-data==0.6.3
terminado==0.17.1
tinycss2==1.2.1
tomli==2.0.1
toolz @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_362wyqvvgy/croot/toolz_1667464079070/work
tornado==6.3.3
tqdm @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_637jfu39ar/croots/recipe/tqdm_1664392693982/work
traitlets==5.10.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
uri-template==1.3.0
urllib3 @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_8fvc4z_gis/croot/urllib3_1673575619550/work
watchdog==3.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.8
webcolors==1.13
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.6.3
Werkzeug==2.2.3
widgetsnbextension==4.0.9
yarl==1.9.2
zstandard @ file:///private/var/folders/nz/j6p8yfhx1mv_0grj5xl4650h0000gp/T/abs_99wz2rcox4/croots/recipe/zstandard_1663827384884/work
```

as does `pip show matplotlib`

```
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.8.0
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: /Users/keith/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: contourpy, cycler, fonttools, kiwisolver, numpy, packaging, pillow, pyparsing, python-dateutil
Required-by:
```

Comment: You should not use pip to install packages that are available in the conda ecosystem, because conda installs precompiled binaries, and pip and conda do not manage packages in the same way. You should use `conda install package` to install packages in conda. Only use pip, if a pacakge is not available in the conda ecosystem. matplotlib is not correctly installed and is not in the environment you being used by Jupyter. You **probably** installed matplotlib into the system python.